# My Release .exe Cant Run on Other PCs

Tags: c++

I have a small program made in Visual Studio 2008 C++ which basically creates and modifies simple text files. I won't copy the code here, but if anyone wants to have a look: www.joggingbenefits.net/hcode.txt

My problem is - I want to make a .exe from this code which can be run on other Windows PCs which dont necessarily have Visual Studio or redist packages installed.

What I've tried so far:

- Change the project configuration from "debug" to "release"
- Switch between all 4 offered runtime libraries (under code generation)
- Saving each one of generated .exe's in my 'Release directory'
- Trying to run each one of those on a PC without Visual Studio installed and none of them works... it only runs for about half a second and it disappears.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I must be missing something very important here... To recap: I did change the compilation mode to Release, and I did try changing Runtime libraries, static/dynamic ones, but none of the produced exes could run...

PS - The programs were all run as administrator and with antiviruses etc. disabled, so it's not that. **Also, I havent linked to any DLLs, all the included libraries are standard.**

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried opening the file with DependencyWalker? You can then see what DLLs it needs, and subsequently check if the VS2008 Runtime required is installed on the other PC

Comment: Add some error messages too (i.e. why they won't run)

Answer (score 0):

Open the .exe with DependencyWalker on the non-working system. It will show what DLLs are missing (usually some VS2008 Runtime).

Additionally in the Windows event manager under errors you should also get an error description when you tried to run your application, as to what it misses. 
When you know what file you are missing, you can just google it, and check to what Redistributable it goes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. My goal however, is not to install anything on my target PC. Everything should be included inside my .exe, so the people I send this program to, don't need to install anything to run it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You've created a command-line program. When Windows opens this program, it creates a command window for the input and output, and when the program is finished it closes the window immediately.

If you open your own command window and run it from there, the window won't close when the program finishes.

You can add a pause at the end of the program if you still want it to run directly but see the output.

```
cout << "Please type any key to finish" << endl;
char ch;
cin >> ch;
```

Comment: This seems like the explanation given the question.

Comment: I've taken a look at the code, it does not instantly terminate, it might throw an error if the file is non-existant, but in that case you would get the "Application has stopped working" error, thus I do not think that this is caused by the application terminating.

Comment: I understand, however, the program should enter in a loop, waiting for a user to select something from the menu - so why does it just skip that part and goes directly to the end?

Comment: @LikBezPujanki, I can only guess it's failing in `display` and calling `exit` early.

Answer (score 0):

Try visiting the Code Generation property page and make sure Runtime Library reads /MT or  /MTd and nothing else (especially /clr). Do a clean build of the project and make sure the output states /MTd and the IDE isn't injecting any other conflicting flags. I don't have a lot of experience with VS2010, but this is all I've ever needed to do with 2008.

Comment: I've done that, as stated, but it did not help, the .exe just runs and closes immediately after

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the DependencyWalker tip that others have mentioned (which is worth doing first), I'd also suggest temporary installing the [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx) on the target PC (it's only a small install).  Run `windbg` and choose `File -> Open Executable` then run with F5.  When the application bombs out you'll get a more meaningful explanation as to where it's going wrong in terms of error messages and call stacks.  My guess would be a missing dll, or maybe a conflict with a different version of a dll than you have on your own system.

Another useful thing you can do with DependencyWalker is to run it on the target PC and choose the `Profile` option, which will give you lots of information as it's searching for dlls.

Note that both of these methods require you to install something on the target PC, but it's only temporary and without doing it you'll just be guessing as to why it's going wrong.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that and report back.

Answer (score -1):

Try installing the "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package" on the machine where the executable is not working.